# What is a single-word synonym for "train of thought" that would cover exposition to someone else and internal philosophising?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am seeking a single word to denote a character's train of connected thoughts, both when they are expounding a view or explaining something to another person and when they are analysing in their mind a set of circumstances or a problem.

Answer (score 2):

**ideation**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ideation)

> the process of forming ideas or images.

**brainwork**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/brainwork)

> 1. work or effort consisting principally or largely of mental activity, thought, imagination, etc., as opposed to physical or manual work.
> 2. the effort of thought, reasoning, planning, or the like; ordered or directed thinking:

**cerebration**

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cerebration)

> The working of the brain; thinking.

**ratiocination**

[Oxford learner's dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ratiocination)

> the process of thinking or arguing about something in a logical way

**deliberation**

[Oxford learner's dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/deliberation)

> 1. [uncountable, countable, usually plural] the process of carefully considering or discussing something

**contemplation**

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/contemplation)

> 1.1 Deep reflective thought

**rumination**

[Oxford learner's dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rumination)

> 1. the act of thinking deeply about something; deep thoughts about something

**cogitation**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cogitation)

> 1. concerted thought or reflection; meditation; contemplation
> 2. the faculty of thinking

Comment: You must have phenomenal Google-Fu to do all this in 6 minutes!

Comment: @Gandalf ~ indeed, read my profile for my methods ;P OneLook dictionary is a Godsend

Answer (score 1):

***Reasoning*** - The action of reason; esp. the process by which one judgement is deduced from another or others which are given. (OED)